# ¿Por qué no estoy recibiendo los eventos emitidos por el servidor de Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, websocket

Estoy tratando de hacer un *piedra, papel o tijera* online usando socket.io y express. Iba avanzando muy rápido en el proyecto hasta que me estanqué aquí y por más documentación que leí y que le pregunté a ChatGPT no lo pude resolver. Los eventos que estoy emitiendo desde el servidor no están llegando al cliente. En general, ningún emit del siguiente código está llegando. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando ingrese a la Room se emita el mensaje a esa room del número de usuarios y del número de la room, de esa manera desde el cliente lo puedo guardar en una cookie y seguirlo usando para hacer comparaciones más adelante. Ya probé con `console.logs` y con `try-catchs`.

```
module.exports = httpServer => {

    const { Server } = require("socket.io");
    const io = new Server(httpServer);

    let elecciones = []; //[{room: 5324, eleccionesRoom: [{ id: 1, nombre: jugador1, arma: piedra}]}]

    const MAX_JUGADORES_POR_SALA = 2;
    let salas = [];

    function compararElecciones(elegido) {
        console.log('Entramos a elegido y: ' + elegido)
    }

    function buscarSalaDisponible(room) {
        if (room) {
            for (const sala of salas) {

                if (sala.sala == room) {
                    // validar si ya hay dos para que no entren
                    ++sala.usuarios
                    return sala.usuarios;
                }

            }
            return null;
        } else {
            console.log('entró al else')
            for (const sala in salas) {

                /* if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[sala].length < MAX_JUGADORES_POR_SALA) {
                    return sala;
                } */
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    function agregarInformacion(array, room, id, nombre, arma) {
        const existingRoom = array.find(obj => obj.room === room);

        if (!existingRoom) {
            const newRoomObject = {
                room: room,
                eleccionesRoom: [{ id, nombre, arma }]
            };
            array.push(newRoomObject);
        } else {
            existingRoom.eleccionesRoom.push({ id, nombre, arma });
        }

        return array;
    }

    function hayDosOMasElecciones(array, room) {
        const existingRoom = array.find(obj => obj.room === room);
        return existingRoom && existingRoom.eleccionesRoom.length >= 2;
    }

    io.on("connection", socket => {
        socket.on('joinRoom', async room => {
            io.emit('suena')
            const found = buscarSalaDisponible(room);
            let salaFinal
            let jugadores = 1

            if (found) {
                socket.join(room);
                console.log('datos que mando: ' + found + ', ' + room)
                console.log(salas)
                salaFinal = room
                jugadores = found
            } else {
                const nuevaSala = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)
                socket.join(nuevaSala)
                console.log(nuevaSala)
                salas.push({ sala: nuevaSala, usuarios: 1 })
                salaFinal = nuevaSala
            }
            console.log('Sala: ' + salaFinal + ' - #Players: ' + jugadores)

            await io.to(salaFinal).emit("informacion", jugadores, salaFinal);

        });

        socket.on('jugada', ({ room, jugador, arma }) => {

            console.log('ROOM parámetro: ' + room)

            agregarInformacion(elecciones, room, socket.id, jugador, arma)
            console.log(elecciones)

            if (hayDosOMasElecciones(elecciones, room)) {
                console.log('Ya eligieron ambos')
                const resultado = compararElecciones(elecciones[room]);
                io.to(room).emit('mostrarResultado', resultado);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Aquí está el código del cliente, que no tiene mucho en realidad porque no he podido empezar a programar qué harán al recibir los eventos porque no puedo recibir ninguno.

```
    const socket = io();
    
    const rb1 = document.querySelector("#rb1")
    const rb2 = document.querySelector("#rb2")
    const rb3 = document.querySelector("#rb3")
    
    const btnElegir = document.querySelector("#elegir")
    const btnCookie = document.querySelector("#borrarCookie")
    
    const cookiesString = document.cookie;
    const cookiesArray = cookiesString.split('; ');
    let cookies = {};
    
    for (const cookie of cookiesArray) {
        const [nombre, valor] = cookie.split('=');
        cookies[nombre] = valor;
    }
    
    btnElegir.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const opciones = document.getElementsByName("rb");
    
        let valorSeleccionado;
        for (const opcion of opciones) {
            if (opcion.checked) {
                valorSeleccionado = opcion.value;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        console.log("Valor seleccionado:", valorSeleccionado);
        socket.emit("jugada", { 'room': cookies.room, 'jugador': cookies.username, 'arma': valorSeleccionado })
    })
    
    btnCookie.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        document.cookie = "room=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
        document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
        window.location.href = '/register'
      
    })
    
    socket.on('suena', ()=>{
        alert('ay sirvió')
    })
    
    socket.on("informacion", (jugadores, numeroSala) => {
        console.log('Sala: '+numeroSala)
        document.cookie = `room=${numeroSala}`
        console.log('Jugadores: '+jugadores)
        // Actualizar el número de jugadores conectados y el número de sala en la pantalla de espera
        //document.getElementById('jugadoresConectados').innerText = `${jugadores} jugadores conectados`;
        //document.getElementById('numeroSala').innerText = `Número de sala: ${numeroSala}`;
      });
    
    
    socket.on('roomReady', () => {
        // La sala está lista, cambiar a la siguiente pantalla o realizar acciones necesarias
        // Por ejemplo, puedes ocultar la pantalla de espera y mostrar la pantalla del juego
        console.log('La sala está llena, lista para jugar.')
        //document.getElementById('pantallaEspera').style.display = 'none';
        // Realizar otras acciones necesarias para iniciar la partida
    });
    
    socket.on('mostrarResultado', (resultado) => {
        console.log('El resultado es: '+ resultado)
        // Implementa la lógica para mostrar el resultado en la interfaz de usuario
    });
```